# How to perform collection operators on the collection itself in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, collections, filter, kotlin

Is there a way to perform a collection operator, such as 'filter', on the collection itself rather then receiving a new filtered collection?
In Ruby most array iterators have a version with an exclamation mark at the end, which means the operation will be performed on the object itself, rather then return a new object.

For example, Instead of doing:

```
var array = IntArray(10) { it }
array = array.filter { it % 2 == 0 }.toIntArray()
```

is there a way to do:

```
val array = IntArray(10) { it }
array.filter! { it % 2 == 0 }
```

or something similar in Kotlin?

Comment: most of the operators return a filtered (or, in general, a transformed) copy of the object because it's more "functional" than altering the initial collection (which is a side effect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are separate operators for doing certain operations in place, for `filter`, there's [`retainAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/retain-all.html):

```
val array = MutableList(10) { it }
array.retainAll { it % 2 == 0 }
println(array) // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Note that you need to use a `MutableList` instead of an `Array`, because arrays are fixed size, so you can't remove items from them.

There are a couple other similar solutions, like [`sort`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html) which works in place and [`sorted`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted.html) which returns a new collection.